# How to update values of a column with multiple values from a query in one table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, row

I want to update the values of a column in my table with new values from a query of that table.

Actually I want to remove some characters from the existed data in one column by a query.

My query is:

```
UPDATE Files
SET [name] = (SELECT
                SUBSTRING([name],
                          CHARINDEX('__', [name]) + 2,
                          LEN([name]) - 1)
              FROM Files)
```

Unfortunately, I get an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please help me how can I update whole data of that column with above query.

Comment: Try this: `UPDATE Files SET [name] = SUBSTRING([name], CHARINDEX('__', [name]) + 2, LEN([name]) - 1)`.

Comment: It works!Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: Assuming that you do this as an ad-hoc data manipulation statement, I recommend that you wrap this update in an explicit transaction using the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement. After the execution of the `UPDATE` statement, perform a check with a `SELECT` statement that confirms that the data has been changed, as you need, and only after that commit the transaction with the help of the `COMMIT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just

```
UPDATE Files
SET [name] = SUBSTRING([name], CHARINDEX('__', [name]) + 2, LEN([name]) - 1);
```

The subquery

```
(SELECT
                SUBSTRING([name],
                          CHARINDEX('__', [name]) + 2,
                          LEN([name]) - 1)
              FROM Files)
```

will returns more than 1 row, because you are selecting the whole rows in the table. Thus it throws the error.